# Browser Mode in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

when I set the browser mode in IE9 to IE8, does that mean, it behaves **exactly** like a IE8 installation or is this some kind of simulated? I am asking because, you know, you can never be sure in IE ;)

Elias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simulated (at least for IE7). We've seen bugs that we could only reproduce in an actual IE7 installation, not using Browser Mode. That being said, we were able to reproduce the vast majority in Browser Mode, so it's still incredibly useful.